# Adding selections to Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering how to add items to a combobox with a few drop down selections. I have attached my code below but nothing showed up. Any advise?

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim i As Integer
i = ComboBox1.Items.Add("This is a new item")
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = i
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @SiddharthRout i am trying to have a drop down list for my combo box.

Comment: When you add an item to a combobox, it is automatically added to the dropdown list

Comment: but for some reason, mine doesn't add any item at all. I am on the right track for the added items?

Comment: no. not exactly... One moment. Posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.AddItem` instead of `.Items.Add` and also no point adding item in combo's change event. I am using a command button to add to it.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "This is a new item"

    '~~> After adding the item this will display the
    '~~> last item added in the combobox
    ComboBox1.Value = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListCount - 1)

    '~~> Display the dropdown via code if you need this as well
    ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub
```

If you want to add items directly from the combobox then you can use this as well. This will add items after you enter something in the combobox and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                              ByVal Shift As Integer)
    '~~> On Key Enter
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        ComboBox1.AddItem "This is a new item"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. I wanted a dropdown selections. Is there any settings I have to set for excel? I can't seems to have it still.

Comment: Where is the combobox? In a userform? or in a worksheet?

Comment: yup.. its on the userform

Comment: Is the above code not adding "This is a new item" to the combobox?

Comment: Maybe you are clearing the combo somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Is it possible that a different version of excel will cause such a problem? I am using 2007.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45565/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-user1204868)